# 'Fast' and 'slow' Eigendirection?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Can someone give an intuition and a definition of what a "fast" and "slow" eigendirection means? A reasonable google search reveals nothing that would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be useful if you include the context in which you encountered this, as it seems to be nonstandard terminology.

Comment: From what I can guess you are asking about asymptotic behavior of solutions ie if one eigenvalue is much larger than the other solutions tend to the associated eigenvector more quickly than the other

Comment: @BenS. The context is in the  case of a phase potrait.

Comment: This might allude to the fact that, if the eigenvalues at a fixed point are $\lambda<\mu<0$ then the trajectories converge to the fixed point and *they are tangent to the eigendirection of $\mu$*. Similar statement for positive eigenvalues, replacing convergence to a fixed point by convergence to infinity.

Comment: @Did Usually when we speaking about positive eigenvalues, we reverse time and get convergence to the fixed point again. I just wanted to say that it won't necessarily go to infinity.